# ASP.MVC Binding to List<int> fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-binding

I'm trying to bind values of radio buttons to `List<int>`. I can see the value is preperly submitted in Fiddler but in Visual Studio the value of `List<int> data` is always *null* in MyAction

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyModel")) {
   @foreach (SomeClass s in Model) {
      for(x=1 ; x< 5; x++){
         @Html.RadioButton("data[" + s.ID + "]", x)}
      }
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
   }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="data_1_" name="data[1]" type="radio" value="1">
<input id="data_1_" name="data[1]" type="radio" value="2">
<input id="data_1_" name="data[1]" type="radio" value="3">
<input id="data_1_" name="data[1]" type="radio" value="4">
<input id="data_1_" name="data[1]" type="radio" value="5">
<input id="data_2_" name="data[2]" type="radio" value="1">
<input id="data_2_" name="data[2]" type="radio" value="2">
<input id="data_2_" name="data[2]" type="radio" value="3">
<input id="data_2_" name="data[2]" type="radio" value="4">
<input id="data_2_" name="data[2]" type="radio" value="5">
```

**Action**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(List<int> data) {
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> The index must be zero-based and unbroken.

[Here is blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) about posting collections of objects, but i am sure that same rule apply to collections of primitives

From the same blog, for collection of primitives you don't need index at all. Just use same name for all of them

That's was answer on you question, but according to your code you have different problem:

As long as you using radio buttons, you don't need collection at all. Give them same name, and in action accept primitive:

HTML:

```
<input id="data_1_" name="data" type="radio" value="1">
<input id="data_2_" name="data" type="radio" value="2">
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(int data) {
    return View();
}
```

Comment: My code is creating groups of radio buttons.(Each loops makes a group of 5 radio buttons) If i use the same name on all radio buttons. I only can select only one radio button.

Comment: @SeehyungLee I see, but you going to define on server in which group which value were selected? Maybe you should reconsider you action, and accept dictionary instead? You will be able to select values anyway(same link from my answer)